# Records from Previous Filter Still Displaying in Salesforce LWC table

Tags: apex, javascript, lightning-web-components, html

I am trying to display account records based on selected custom picklist values.

**Example:**

If selected Picklist 2 value is A, all account records having A Picklist 2 values must be displayed.

[image]

For testing, I changed Picklist 2 value to B, but instead of displaying just all account records having B values, it also displays the previous records.

[image]

When I select A picklist value again, table just adds records with A values. It just keeps on adding and adding records to be displayed, instead of displaying the necessary results.

I already made several revisions, first ones do not have values. Until I reached part where I finally got records displayed.

Meanwhile, here are the current codes I am stuck with:

**accountLWC.html**

```
<template>  
    
    <div>
        <lightning-combobox
            class="slds-m-bottom_small slds-m-left_small"
            name="selectBox"
            label="Picklist 2"
            value={value}
            placeholder="--None--"
            options={picklist2Options}
            onchange={findAccountResult} >
        </lightning-combobox>    
    </div>    
    
    <table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered slds-table_col-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr class="slds-line-height_reset">
                <th scope="col">
                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="accountPicklist1">Picklist 1</div>
                </th>
                <th scope="col">
                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="accountName">Account Name</div>
                </th>  
                <th scope="col">
                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="accountPicklist2">Picklist 2</div>
                </th>  
            </tr>
        </thead>
        
        <tbody>
           
            <template if:true={mapData}>
                <template for:each={mapData} for:item="keyValue">
                    <tr key={keyValue.key} class="slds-hint-parent">
                        <th scope="col">
                            <div>{keyValue.key}</div>
                        </th>
                        <th scope="col">
                            <template for:each={keyValue.value} for:item="mapValue">
                                <div key={mapValue.Name}>
                                    {mapValue.Name}
                                </div> 
                            </template>
                        </th>
                        <th scope="col">
                            <template for:each={keyValue.value} for:item="mapValue2">
                                <div key={mapValue2.Picklist2}>
                                    {mapValue2.Picklist2}
                                </div> 
                            </template>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </template>
            </template> 
        </tbody>
        
    </table>
    
    <center>
        <template if:true= {noRecordsFound}>
            --No Account Records Found--
        </template>
    </center>
</template>
```

**accountLWC.js**

```
import { LightningElement, track, wire } from 'lwc';

import getDataFromApex from '@salesforce/apex/AccountController.getAccountData';

export default class accountLWC extends LightningElement {

    @track mapData = [];

    @track noRecordsFound = true;

    @track picklist2Options = [
        {value: 'A', label: 'A'},
        {value: 'B', label: 'B'},
        {value: 'C', label: 'C'}
    ];
    @track value = '--None--';

    findAccountResult(event) {
        const accPicklist2 = event.target.value;

        if(accPicklist2) {
            getDataFromApex ( {accPicklist2}) 
            .then(result => {
            
                if(result) {
                    let tempMapData = [];
                    for(var key in result) {
                        tempMapData.push({key:key,value:result[key]});
                        this.noRecordsFound = false;
                        
                    } 
                    this.mapData = tempMapData;       
                }
                                 
            })
        } 
        else {
            this.mapData = undefined;
            this.noRecordsFound = true;
        }
    }

}
```

**AccountController.cls**

```
public class AccountController{

    @AuraEnabled

    
    public static Map<String, List<AccountWrapper>> getAccountData(String accPicklist2) 
    {
   
     Map<String, List<AccountWrapper>> mapPicklist1 = new Map<String, List<AccountWrapper>>();
     Map<String, Integer> accPicklist1CountMap = new Map<String, Integer>();
     

     List<Account> accountList = [SELECT Name, Picklist1__c, Picklist2__c
            FROM Account 
            WHERE Picklist1__c != null AND Picklist2__c =: accPicklist2 
            ORDER BY Picklist1__c];       
         

     for(Account accObj:accountList)
     {
      List<AccountWrapper> accWrapperList = new List<AccountWrapper>();
      
      if(mapPicklist1.containsKey(accObj.Picklist1__c))
      {
       
       accWrapperList = mapPicklist1.get(accObj.Picklist1__c);
       
       
       accWrapperList.add(new AccountWrapper(accObj));
       
       mapPicklist1.put(accObj.Picklist1__c, accWrapperList);
       
      
       accPicklist1CountMap.put(accObj.Picklist1__c, accWrapperList.size());
      }
      else
      {
       
       accWrapperList.add(new AccountWrapper(accObj));
       mapPicklist1.put(accObj.Picklist1__c, accWrapperList);
       
       
       accPicklist1CountMap.put(accObj.Picklist1__c, accWrapperList.size());
      }
     }
     
     return mapPicklist1;

    }
   
    public Class AccountWrapper {
     
     public AccountWrapper(Account acc)
     {
      this.Name = acc.Name;
      this.Picklist1 = acc.Picklist1__c;
      this.Picklist2 = acc.Picklist2__c;
     }
     
     @AuraEnabled
     public String Name {get;set;}
     @AuraEnabled
     public String Picklist1 {get;set;}
     @AuraEnabled
     public String Picklist2 {get;set;}
     
    }

    
   }
```

Would appreciate if anyone could help me get progress on this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the `cacheable=true` from the apex method as you are calling it imperatively.

Just reset the `mapData` in the wired method callback.

```
if(result) {
    this.mapData = Object.keys(result).map((key) => ({ key, value:result[key] }));
}
```